# Define a type that inherits from a vector in Julia

Tags: function, types, julia, overloading, abstract-type

I would like to create a type (say, `my_vector`) that behaves exactly like a `Vector`, so that I can pass it to all the functions that take Vectors. In addition to that, I want to create special functions exclusively for `my_vector`, that do not work for generic Vectors.

So, for instance, if `A` is a `Matrix` and `typeof(b)` is `my_vector`, I want to be able to solve a linear system using `A\b`, to recover its length with `length(b)`, or to access its elements with `b[index]`.

At the same time, I want to define a specific function that can take objects of type `my_vector` as parameters, but that does not take objects of type `Vector`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close yet, but this IMHO needs details where you have encountered problems. All of this is very well described in the official docs (docs.julialang.org).

Comment: I have added an answer, as although it is true, that as @phipsgabler comments, it is described in the manual, I think it might be non obvious what one needs to do exactly to make things work (in JuliaData ecosystem there are several custom vector implementations and it was far from obvious how one should correctly implement them).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in general.

What you can do is define your `my_vector` type as subtype of `AbstractVector`. Then all functions accepting `AbstractVector` will also accept your type. What you need to implement for `AbstractVector` is listed in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array.

Then if you want your `my_vector` type to also have functionalities that `Vector` has but `AbstractVector` does not have you need to implement yourself methods for functions that are specifically defined to only accept `Vector`. There are 49 such methods in Julia standard installation and you can find their list by writing `methodswith(Vector)`. Most likely you will not need them all but only a small selection of such methods e.g. `push!` or `pop!`.

Having said that this will not ensure that everything that accepts `Vector` will accept your `my_vector`, as if some package accepts only `Vector` you will have to perform the same process for functions defined in this package.

In summary - check if `AbstractVector` is enough for you, as most likely it is and then it is simple. If it is not the case then doing what you want is difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just had a hard time understanding the use of interfaces in Julia, despite the documentation.

Comment: Here you have an example of fully functional https://github.com/JuliaData/PooledArrays.jl/blob/main/src/PooledArrays.jl custom array implementation that hopefully should be easy enough to follow (you do not need to read all the details - rather what methods are defined and their signatures).